# How to load data in second JavaScript form and than parse to the first JavaScript form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, kendo-ui

could someone help me out.
The problem I am getting now is, that I am loading huge amount of data from the server to a pivot table. For that I am using the J Query method type O Data. By loading the data from the server, the webpage freeze nearly for 6 min. I need some information to show to the user that is working.

First Question: What is the best method to do it?
My idea was to load the data in a difference JavaScript file, than to parse the data to the pivot table code is the First JavaScript form. So the screen will not freeze and I can display a progress spinner.
Second question: how can do it?

Comment: I think the first question to ask is; do you really need to send a huge amount of data to the web browser? If you are just calculating some value to display to the user, then you should do that on the server, not in the browser. Can your data be paged? Then it would be easy to show a "loading" indicator until an ajax request finishes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decrease page loading time then i suggest you to use [`Datatable`](http://datatables.net/).

You may try pagination for displaying data instances of load all data at a time.

Best method for this is [`Datatable`](http://datatables.net/)

You can find it's examples from [Ajax datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)